# Replace word pattern using sed

Tags: sed

I have a file with the following structure:

```
prefix_postfix123456 some text1  other stuff
prefix_postfix88989898 some text2 other stuff
```

I want to replace all prefix* to prefix, and keep the rest of the file as is:

```
prefix some text1  other stuff
prefix some text2  other stuff
```

I have try this:

```
sed -i 's/prefix[\s]*/prefix/g' fileName
```

But this doesn't work.

Could you please show me how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your data is separated by spaces, then this should do what you want:

```
sed -i 's/\bprefix[^ ]*/prefix/g' fileName
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple method

```
 sed 's/_[^ ]\+//' FileName
```

**OutPut:**

```
prefix some text1  other stuff
prefix some text2 other stuff
```